# How to fetch user detail using Apple id ? Is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, sdk, apple-id

I want to fetch user's some details using user's apple's credentials. Similar of Facebook and Google+.

So, Is it possible ? If Yes, Please share any link or suggestions regarding it.

Regards,

Comment: No this is not possible and would be a huge privacy breach.

Comment: Okay, Can we authenticate user's login detail instead of fetching any personal detail ?

Comment: No, Apple has not released any API for developers to use the Apple ID to login. Just imagine that you could, some one could get you Apple ID and password and then buy stuff from iTunes. This should not be possible.

Comment: this question is pretty much [a duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814750/using-apple-id-as-for-iphone-application-authentication).